# What hardware or software solutions can be used to prevent of stack overflows?

Tags: hardware, architecture

What is the hardware solution for prevention of stack overflow?
For example, when we want to design a new operating system, how can we prevent stack overflows?

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused as to if you are asking about hardware or software. You ask for a hardware solution, but then ask how to prevent this in the design of an OS which is not hardware.

Comment: @jobyTaffey is a pretty serious embedded guy, but this really seems like more of a software question to myself.

Comment: @jpc, maybe I should get better at coding then. I have had a few.

Comment: @Kellenjb - I believe the question is referring not to the prevention of overallocation of memory, but to the prevention of malicious stack overflows that execute arbitrary code.  That is a memory mapping/architecture/chip design question, which I believe is on topic.

Comment: Wish I could [vote not to close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/146495) right now...

Comment: @Farnaz Are you concerned with ensuring that your algorithms fit inside your allocated stack in RAM, or preventing an attacker from misusing the stack to execute code?

Comment: @Joby - That was a better solution to the open/close problem than my guessing...

Comment: Hello

Thank you for all answering, i want to know that What can we resolve stack overflow problem in the operating system level ?

Thank you

Comment: @Farnaz, It just happens that there is a site dedicated to dealing with Stack overflows.

Answer (score 4):

If code can be statically confirmed not to have any direct or indirect recursion, static analysis can yield a worst-case stack usage.  Make sure the stack is big enough and there won't be any stack overflow.  The biggest difficulty is that it may be hard to determine which functions can be called by which function pointers.  For example, if one function pointer can point to foo1() or foo2(), another can point to bar1() or bar2(), and foo1() calls the second function pointer (thus reaching bar1 or bar2) there would be no possibility of recursion, but if the compiler can't determine that the second pointer can only point to bar1() or bar2() it might not know that.

If an application can be determined to be non-recursive, and if the static-analysis worst-case call-graph isn't too much worse than what can actually happen, it may be possible to avoid the stack entirely and allocate all variables statically.  In some cases (especially on architectures without efficient indexing) this approach may substantially improve performance compared with using a stack.

From a security standpoint, a good means of avoiding stack/buffer overflow exploits is to avoid storing real program-counter addresses anywhere that "normal" pointers can access.  Store the program-counter stack entirely separately from the parameter/auto-variable stack, and don't store any function pointers directly.  Instead have every "function pointer" be an index into a table of functions having the same signature, and check the index to ensure it's in range before using it; if two or more groups of functions have different security implications and should be called by completely different pointers, tweak the signature of one group if needed to make it different from the other (so a calls to a function in the first group can't be converted to a call to a function in the second).

Comment: I can only add that the newest GCC (4.6) will add support for this type of conservative stack size estimation.

Answer (score 3):

The Harvard Architecture provides some protection from stack overflow attacks. [Are Harvard architecture computers immune to arbitrary code injection and execution attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954556/are-harvard-architecture-computers-immune-to-arbitrary-code-injection-and-executi)

But, at the OS level you might want to consider having a [non-executable stack](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/kernel/non-exec.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may be surprised, but one of the options is **stackless hardware architecture** (either real or emulated) ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485146/tail-calls-in-architectures-without-a-call-stack)). Apparently, no stack - no stack overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Some microcontrollers provide for a hardware trap when the stack is at a predefined threshold.  This can either be used to shutdown gracefully, or to page the stack out to external RAM and start afresh. There's a similar "underflow" trap to page the old stack back in.